# Inserir múltiplos objetos com Doctrine Dbal

Tags: doctrine-2, silex

Estou usando o silex em conjunto com o doctrine dbal 2.5.

Como eu faço para inserir múltiplos objetos no banco com o Doctrine dbal?

Lendo a documentação não achei nada que possibilitasse isso, tem alguma forma de fazer isto?

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente, com o Doctrine, deve-se persistir múltiplos objetos com `persist` antes de usar o comando `flush`:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $em->persist($object);
}
$em->flush();
```

Se a pergunta diz respeito a ter múltiplos `INSERT` na mesma query, o Doctrine não permite isso. A razão é que com isso o Doctrine não consegue obter o identificador de cada linha e colocar no objeto correspondente.

Segundo a própria documentação deles:

> First of all, this syntax is only supported on mysql and newer postgresql versions. Secondly, there is no easy way to get hold of all the generated identifiers in such a multi-insert when using AUTO_INCREMENT or SERIAL and an ORM needs the identifiers for identity management of the objects. Lastly, insert performance is rarely the bottleneck of an ORM. Normal inserts are more than fast enough for most situations and if you really want to do fast bulk inserts, then a multi-insert is not the best way anyway, i.e. Postgres COPY or Mysql LOAD DATA INFILE are several orders of magnitude faster.
>   These are the reasons why it is not worth the effort to implement an abstraction that performs multi-inserts on mysql and postgresql in an ORM.

Mais detalhes aqui: [Doctrine2 Batch Processing](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/08/07/doctrine2-batch-processing.html).

Comment: O dbal nao usa o entity manager.